# Is possible to referance the global.json sdk version in a .fsproj TarkgetFramework?

Tags: .net, f#

Wondering if there is an easy way to set the version for all my projects in an f#. It would seem like we should be able to do this by referencing `global.json`, but I haven't quite got that to work.

Also happy to explore completely different solutions the main goal here is given a set of f# projects is there an easy way to set there version from a single place. Seems odd to have to set this for each project, but clearly useful.

Comment: It's often done in a build script.

Comment: Do you want to set version of project, e.g. `<Version>1.2.0</Version>` or target framework, e.g. `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` ?

Comment: I suspect what you're asking is this: [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Thanks I will try to give this a go here soon.